# Purpose of one-eyed statue in Skyloft?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

In Skyloft, there is bird-like statue with a ruby for its right eye, with nothing in its left.  It is located on the top of the rock platforms that traverse the left side of the small lake, on the way up to the waterfall cave.  Does this statue have a purpose?

I've noticed that the statue rotates depending on whether it is day or night, but is that the only thing it does?

Comment: Ah, I kept meaning to ask myself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's relevant to the games story, so you don't need to worry about it for now. However, if you really want to know...

***late game spoiler warning***

> After collecting the Song of the Hero, and completing the the Skyloft silent realm, you will receive an item that goes inside of the statues other eye. Doing this will reveal the final temple, containing the three pieces of the Triforce.

Comment: I don't want to read the spoiler, but I'm pretty far into the game... I think I only have the final boss left.  Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @John You need to do something with this statue in order to beat the game, so you have more than the final boss left.

Comment: good!  I really don't want this game to end...