# What do I need to do with a parrot statue that is missing a red eye?

Tags: zelda-skyward-sword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Purpose of one-eyed statue in Skyloft?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/42722/purpose-of-one-eyed-statue-in-skyloft)

In Skyward Sword, there's a bird statue near the waterfall (it is the only one in that area) and it seems to be missing a red stone that use to be one of its eyes. 
This same statue seems to be looking at Skyloft during the day and at night it seems to be looking in the opposite direction.

At the beginning of the game a man tells you about the statue and that it has lost one of its eyes. Right now nobody is there And I still can't find any side quest that has to do with the statue.

What do I do with that statue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That statue is relevant very, *very* late in the game. I'll write when in the spoiler tag

> You get the missing red eye after finishing the final silent realm, once placing it in the statue, it unlocks the final dungeon, containing the Triforce

Answer (score 3):

The red stone eye you mention is known as the Stone of Trials.

[This wiki](http://www.ign.com/wikis/the-legend-of-zelda-skyward-sword/The_Silent_Realm_-_Skyloft) describes what you need to do to earn it. Keep in mind that this is something that happens near the end of the game (and is not a side quest.)

> You will get the Stone of Trials (this is the stone eye that you are looking for) for completing the final Silent Realm. This can be placed in a bird statue in the northwest region of Skyloft, on the north tip of the lake. One of the bird statue's eyes is still in place, a red crystal that matches the Stone of Trials. Placing the Stone of Trials in the bird statue causes it to fire a few cannon rounds at the bottom of the Statue of the Godess, exposing the final dungeon: Sky Keep.